# Sorting a list of string dates with no year but with 29th Feb

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

I have a list of dates that are without a year component, which I need to sort. My code to sort them fails for 29th Feb. and raises a `ValueError: day is out of range for month` exception instead:

```
from datetime import datetime
a = [
    '7-Mar 11:20:33', '7-Mar 10:30:22','22-Mar 22:33:11', '31-Mar 11:22:33', 
    '25-Mar 03:04:05', '1-Jan 00:00:00', '29-Feb 02:11:10'
]
a.sort(key=lambda date: datetime.strptime(date, "%d-%b %H:%M:%S"))
```

Is there any way to sort these dates with default leap year?

After sorting, the list should be:

```
['1-Jan 00:00:00', '29-Feb 02:11:10', '7-Mar 10:30:22', '7-Mar 11:20:33',
 '22-Mar 22:33:11', '25-Mar 03:04:05', '31-Mar 11:22:33']
```

Comment: Without a year, a default is used (1900). There is no leap day in 1900. Add a year to your values when parsing.

Comment: there is no such 29-Feb-2017

Comment: What is your *expected output*, do you need to be able to sort any given date without a year and allow for leap days, always?

Comment: I don't get year in the list of the dates. Is there any other way. Is there a way i can override the default and specify leap year as my default year ?

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ: nor is there a 29th of February in 1900 (edited my initial comment).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I agree with you. But in my case, we want to sort the dates. The assumption is that they are from same year but we don't know the year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dates have no year, so the default, 1900, is used:

```
>>> datetime.strptime('7-Mar 11:20:33', "%d-%b %H:%M:%S")
datetime.datetime(1900, 3, 7, 11, 20, 33)
```

1900 is not a leap year, so the 29th of February 1900 doesn't exist and the exception is raised.

If you must support parsing dates with leap days and no year, add in a year of your choosing as a string to the value to be parsed, like `'1904 '`, and parse out that extra number:

```
>>> datetime.strptime('1904 29-Feb 02:11:10', "%Y %d-%b %H:%M:%S")
datetime.datetime(1904, 2, 29, 2, 11, 10)
```

Just add the year as a string when parsing:

```
a.sort(key=lambda date: datetime.strptime('1904 ' + date, "%Y %d-%b %H:%M:%S"))
```

Demo using your sample data:

```
>>> sorted(a, key=lambda date: datetime.strptime('1904 ' + date, "%Y %d-%b %H:%M:%S"))
['1-Jan 00:00:00', '29-Feb 02:11:10', '7-Mar 10:30:22', '7-Mar 11:20:33', '22-Mar 22:33:11', '25-Mar 03:04:05', '31-Mar 11:22:33']
```

Comment: I like this solution.

Comment: @user1768610 just be warned if you're guessing a year that any attempt at using a day *name* is going to be iffy.

Comment: @JonClements: but for *sorting* this is just fine.